# Send an array by value as an parameter?

Tags: c++, arrays

I made a very simple code, to learn c++. And i made the discovery that when i send a array created on the stack to another function, the funtion change the source array - this it not the case with other variables. Like an int or something.

Why is it like that?

Code:

```
void ByValue(int arr[], int size)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {
      arr[i] += 1;
    }
}

void  SimpleArray()
{
    int arr[3];

    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
    {
      arr[i] = i+1;
      cout << "Element [" << i << "] is " << arr[i] << endl;
    }
    cout << endl;
    ByValue(arr, 3);// <-- should be by value
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
    {
        cout << "Element after change [" << i << "] is " << arr[i] << endl;  // <-- this shouldent change ?
    } 
    cout << endl;

}
```

gives the output:

```
Element [0] is 1
Element [1] is 2
Element [2] is 3

Element after change [0] is 2
Element after change [1] is 3
Element after change [2] is 4
```

The second output should be the same as the first if it was passed by value,
but now is it like i used a pointer?

Comment: use `std::array` to achieve passing arays by value

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Effectively, the prototype  for `ByValue` is

`void ByValue(int* arr, int size)`

i.e. the array has *decayed* to a pointer type. So therefore modifications to the array *are* reflected in the caller.

Note that the notation `*(arr + n)` is *identical* to `arr[n]`.

Comment: Note: the parameter has been *adjusted* to pointer. The argument *decays* because the parameter is pointer.

Comment: But the array is still on the stack right? So the poniter in byValue points to the stack?

Comment: The array certainly has automatic storage duration. Pointers can point to those types too.

Answer (score 1):

Passing an array to a function decays it to pointer. So actually changes are being made in the original array. arr is nothing but the address of the first element in the array. And that address is being passed to the function. So in the function if you do

`arr[index] = value;`, 
it is broken down as `*(arr + index) = value;` which will make changes in your original array as `arr` is the same address as the address of the original array's first element.